# VBA Excel: Copy column with start position and destination position

Tags: excel, vba, copy, range

I would like to copy the values of a column from one worksheet to another worksheet that already has rows.

I want to add the values in column A in worksheet "source" to column X in worksheet "dest".
But I want to skip the first 2 rows of the source column, and the values should be inserted after the 2000th row.

For example like this:

```
Workbook.Sheets("source").Columns("A3:A").Copy Destination:=nDestSheet.Range("X2001")
```

But VBA is telling me about a Type Mismatch.
I guess I am just doing something wrong in regards to the syntax.

Can somebody help please?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.Columns` accepts column number or letter, not a range. That's not exactly important as "A3:A" is not a valid range anyway.

You probably want

```
With Workbook.Sheets("source")
  .Range(.Range("A3"), .Columns("A").Cells(.UsedRange.Rows(.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row)).Copy Destination:=nDestSheet.Range("X2001")
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

How about a simple:

```
Workbook.Sheets("source").Columns("A").Copy Destination:=nDestSheet.Range("X2001")
```

Comment: Please give more explanation. Welcome to stack overflow.